# How to remove sliding effect while moving one state to another in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, ionic-framework

I am trying to move one view to another on button click> I am able to move one one view to second .But while moving it start slide from right to left .I need to stop that sliding . mean I need to learn various type of way to move one view to another using animation  (left to right or up to down  or no animation  or down to up) .

Check my code here
http://goo.gl/Q2k6mf

click **preview** button .And type **"ABW"** and select **"ABW" row** .it download data from server and after that it move to second view with sliding why ? I need to stop that sliding .

**Secondly** 
I am downloading the data in first controller .is there any better way to hit server or call webservice before moving to second view ?

```
   $scope.rowclick=function(station){
     $scope.SEARCH.stationCode=station.stationCode;
     $scope.SEARCH.selected = true;


            $ionicLoading.show();
            $http.get("http://caht.firstrail.com/FGRailApps/jservices/rest/a/departure?crsCode="+ $scope.SEARCH.stationCode).then(function(data){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                 $state.go('departuredashboard')
                console.log(data);
            },function(error){
                $ionicLoading.hide();
                alert("error"+error);
            })
   }
```

Actually I need that data on second view ?
here is code
https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

Comment: there are too many questions

Comment: and the code you provided , gives an error.

Comment: nav-transition="none" , add this to your < ion-nav-view> , and see if it works.

Comment: more info here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/ . Don't surprise if your question gets downvotes

Comment: @KaranKumar checking code wait ...!!

Comment: Its CORS issue with that code. @PallaviSharma

Comment: @KaranKumar it is working please check again http://goo.gl/BzhY3A and your  nav-transition="none" not working

Comment: @cor I am also able to move one view to another i need to remove sliding effer

Comment: any update of this Question

Comment: error still remains.

Comment: :(..:( what type of error you getting

Comment: check this https://dl.dropbox.com/s/l2dtrxmnsurccxt/www.zip?dl=0

Comment: please run index.html file

Comment: @KaranKumar got it ?

Comment: put this in your .run ionic platform ready 

$ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none');

Comment: could you please send any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to remove that animation, Its so sweet, but here you go.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider){
     $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none')
          // rest of the config    
})
```

Edit: For your second question: here is a code snippet as to how to use resolve of ui-router

```js
.state('stateName',{ 
 url:'/SomeUrl',        
resolve: {
       resolvedData: function ($http) {
         var result = $http.get(yourUrlHere).success(function (data) {
                         return data;
                      }).error(function (err) {
                         return err;
                      });
                         return result;
                }
         }
  })
```

And in your controller , inject "resolvedData"

Comment: yes ...it is sweet but I just want to know how to remove .But thanks for answering..could you please tell second Question .mean I need to call webservice before moving to second view . i need to send data on second view.I need better way one way I already writtern

Comment: use ui-router's resolve function. 
Check This Out:  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve

Answer (score 0):

1. To disable navigation transitions use `$ionicConfigProvider`

   $ionicConfigProvider.views.transition('none') in config box
2. To load data before controller user `resolve`:

```js
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
      url: '/',
      templateUrl: 'template1.html'
    })
    .state('state2', {
      url: '/state2',
      templateUrl: 'template2.html',
      controller: 'ACtrl',
      resolve:{ myData : ['$http',function($http) {
          var ULR ="your URL";
          return $http.get(URL);
        }]}
    })
    
    });
```

Now you can insert `myData` in your second controller just like any other  Service.